# How to create sugested list in livetable macro in xWiki

Tags: javascript, velocity, xwiki

I have a livetable macro with custom json where people can filter value, but they have to type the value, I want them to select already determined value selected by me.

The field i want to modifie is source :

Current value:

```
#set($columnsProperties = {
    "Source" : { "type" : "text", "sortable" : true}
})
```

Exemple:

[image]

It seam that **list** corresponding to what I want to do, but I dont understand where i am supposed to write the selected value :

```
#set($columnsProperties = {
    "Source" : { "type" : "list", "sortable" : true}
})
```

[image]

In my JSON, the data look like this:

```
#set($dataset = [
{
    "doc_viewable" : true,
    "Source" : "Hive",
    ...
```

But value aren't auto retrieve and the documentation doesn't show any exemple

https://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Livetable%20Macro